# Is there a way to read environment variables inside override.ts with AWS Amplify Auth

Tags: aws-amplify

I used to AWS Amplify Auth for a social login, recently.

and, for social provider setting, I'm trying to use amplify auth override.

docs is here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/override/

for security reason, I don't want write the secrets inside override.ts like client id, client secrets, etc.

Is it possible to read environment variables in override.ts?
or any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Amplify CLI retained the information in `amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json` such as project environment information and others resources information.
I used `amplify-meta.json` as a module.
There is a StackName with the value of `amplify-[PROJECT_NAME]-[ENVIRONMENT_NAME]-[PROECT_NUMBER]`. So we can get the environment name by deconstructing the string.

**override.ts**

```
export function override(resources: AmplifyAuthCognitoStackTemplate) {
  const amplifyMetaJson = require('../../../amplify-meta.json');
  const envName = amplifyMetaJson.providers.awscloudformation.StackName.split("-").slice(-2, -1).pop();
  console.log("Environment for cloudformation => ", envName);
}
```

Note: This is the temporary solution of an evil way. It is better to fix the issue.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9063